# Scatter chart series with uneven data intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2010, charts

I have two series of data I wish to plot on the same graph: Series 1 has 10 data points, Series 2 has 15 data points.

I want to show both series on the same chart (presumably Scatter) with the points covering the same distance on the X Axis (i.e. Series 2 points are closer together and the final Series 1 and Series 2 displaying at the same point on the X Axis).

At the moment I am using a Scatter Chart.

EDIT here's my data, these are the two series:

- 11.69    11.70
- 11.87   11.70
- 12.38   11.77
- 11.89   11.96
- 11.57   12.77
- 11.67   13.16
- 12.23   13.08
- 12.21   13.28
- 12.52   12.87
- 12.24   12.82
- 12.12   12.82
- 12.21   12.89
- 12.25
- 12.49
- 12.47
- 12.78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Scatter Chart, each series' points should be located based upon the X and Y coordinates of each point.  As long as those are accurate, and the Chart's axis are both formatted to show the entire data range, it should automatically locate all points of both series properly.  If you need a sample, post your data, and we can use it to generate one.

**EDIT:**  Using your data, here's the chart I created.  For the first series (16 values), use the values 1-16 for the X Axis.  To create an evenly spaced second series, divide the 16 values into 12, then use those values for it's X axis.  Your final result will look something like this:

[image: Uneven series]

If you need a different spacing/distribution for your second series, you'll need to plug different numbers into its X Axis.

Comment: heres my data, these are the two series:11.69 11.70
11.87 11.70
12.38 11.77
11.89 11.96
11.57 12.77
11.67 13.16
12.23 13.08
12.21 13.28
12.52 12.87
12.24 12.82
12.12 12.82
12.21 12.89
12.25 
12.49 
12.47 
12.78

Comment: Ok, I got what appears to be 28 values-how do they separate into two series?  Also, assuming these are Y values, I don't see any X values.

Comment: edited question values are y values for both series. I don't have y values.

Comment: HERO! if i had upvotes to give i would